# How can I create a finger scrollable Textbox in WM 6.5?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, textbox

I just noticed something weird in WM 6.5 emulators. Unlike 6.1 where finger panning kind of worked, the only way to scroll a Textbox appears to be through scrollbars.

This behaviour is in contrast to what they have done for comboboxes: they are now gesture-friendly without the programmer's intervention. I.e. the user can select a choice from a standard drop down menu by panning and scrolling. Previously, you had to use the embedded scrollbar. The combobox's case implies that MS took some measures to provide standard gesture support for classic finger gestures, yet I cannot see something similar for textboxes. This makes me ask the following:

- Is there anything that can be done to make textboxes finger scrollabe easily?

Note that I refer to managed .NET CF development. It is my understanding that in native development I could use the new Gestures API to achieve the scrolling effect. Yet, I am not sure if there is an easier and more straightforward method that I have missed.

Comment: There are way too many double-triple-negatives in this post for me to even parse what you are asking.

Comment: Fixed for your eyes only..! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a textarea and limit it to two rows: one for text, one for a scrollbar.

Comment: I am trying to avoid scrollbars altogether. I want to scroll through a text box by pressing my finger on the text and move it up an down "iphone like".

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the gesture api, there are managed wrappers for it...

http://blog.markarteaga.com/CategoryView,category,Samples.aspx